# The mortar between my patio bricks is crumbling away

Tags: brick, mortar, patio

The bricks on my front porch have some sort of mortar that crumbles away more and more every time I pull a weed from it. You could pick this stuff away with an awl but it is not  just sand that you might put between yard pavers. The depth from the top of the bricks to this "mortar" is about half an inch and growing. I believe this patio is about 12 years old. 
My questions are:

1. What is this stuff?
2. Can I add more over the top of existing?
3. How can I stop it from crumbling?

Answer (score 2):

1. sounds like mortar
2. if it's mortar, you can re tuck-point it all. Scrape/grind out the loose stuff, put new stuff back.
3. not much you can do if it's exposed to the elements. How is your porch constructed? Are these bricks on a patio or some form of foundation?

Comment: Thanks DA01.  The bricks are on a patio fully exposed to the elements.  So far they are sturdy and level.  I'll scrape away some of the old and add some new mortar to keep them in good shape.